# remove namespaces of multiple tags

Tags: xslt, namespaces, xml-namespaces

i've just learned some xslt langauge and i have a problem. I'm trying to remove this namespace without success.

Original xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file_information xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.chellodmc.com/files/dmc_media_delivery.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.chellodmc.com/file0073/dmc_media_delivery.xsd http://www.chellodmc.com/files/dmc_media_delivery.xsd">
            <asset_data soa:23946923649236489>
            <upn>TEST_Sintec_HD</upn>
            <title>NLD_NGC_C_Man United - Chelsea - Sunday @17.00</title>
            <version>High Definition</version>
            <duration>00:30</duration>
            <tc_in>23:00:00:00</tc_in>
            <tc_out>23:00:30:00</tc_out>
            <aspect_ratio>16X9</aspect_ratio>
            <segment>
                <sequence>1</sequence>
                <tc_in>23:00:00:00</tc_in>
                <tc_out>23:00:30:00</tc_out> 
                <comment></comment>  
            </segment>
            </asset_data>
        </file_information>
```

Expected output xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <file_information>
            <asset_data>
            <upn>TEST_Sintec_HD</upn>
            <title>NLD_NGC_C_Man United - Chelsea - Sunday @17.00</title>
            <version>High Definition</version>
            <duration>00:30</duration>
            <tc_in>23:00:00:00</tc_in>
            <tc_out>23:00:30:00</tc_out>
            <aspect_ratio>16X9</aspect_ratio>
            <segment>
                <sequence>1</sequence>
                <tc_in>23:00:00:00</tc_in>
                <tc_out>23:00:30:00</tc_out> 
                <comment></comment>    
            </segment>
            </asset_data>
        </file_information>
```

what would be your suggestion?
Many thanks!

Comment: Where is the value of the attribute in `<asset_data soa:23946923649236489>` and where is the namespace declaration of the `soa` prefix used in that attribute name? The sample as posted could not be processed by an XML parser as an attribute needs to have a value and as the namespace needs to be declared.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: No worries guys i've found a solution , thanks for helping anyway!